# how to create and save applescript file programmatically

Tags: objective-c, file-io, applescript, osx-mavericks

I want to create a applescript menu file for a application, I need to edit that file so i have script in text file and i have edit the file and save it as a script file, but unfortunately its not detecting as script file by application "Outlook Mac 2011" and even when i open this file into script editor and try to save it's throwing error of unable to save so please help me on this

```
        userpath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        userpath = [userpath stringByAppendingString:@"/Microsoft User Data/Outlook Script Menu Items/"];
        userpath = [userpath stringByAppendingString:@"Create New Conference Event.scptd"];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:userpath contents:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];

        NSDictionary* errorDis = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:userpath] error:&errorDis];
```

then I am trying to compile the edited file

```
NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
        NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
        [appleScript compileAndReturnError:&errors];
```

I am getting this error

```
Printing description of errors:
{
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-43";
}
```

Comment: What is the content.? And also the extension for a Applescript Text file is ".applescript"

Comment: but the apple script witch use by outlook use has scpt extention

Comment: Yes. But you have .scptd  which is for a bundle And the content is text. A Applescript text file may still work and would save you a lot of trouble trying to create a compiled file type

Comment: how can i create the compiled version because i am not able to read the content of scpt ext?

Comment: See my answer. I am not sure why you need the NSAppleScript ? but On my 10.9.x Mac I can open the file in Applescript and it is compiled. I used a simple 'say "hello"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 'Content' is a NSString.

Just change the **scptd** extension to **scpt**.

```
userpath = [userpath stringByAppendingString:@"Create New Conference Event.scpt"];

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:userpath contents:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil];
```

It seems that just doing this does save a compiled file that works when opened.

UPDATE*

---

An alternative is to run a script to store the outlook script using NSApplescript.

Example Code:

```
 NSString * scriptContent = @"say \"hello\"";
    NSString * scriptPath =@"\"/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/theScript.scpt\"";

    NSString * content =[NSString  stringWithFormat: @"set script_text to MakeScript()\n my RunMaker(script_text)\n on RunMaker(script_text)\n set file_spec to (%@) \n store script script_text in file_spec replacing yes \n end RunMaker \n on MakeScript() \n script \n  %@ \n end script \nend MakeScript",scriptPath,scriptContent];

    NSLog(@" content %@", content);

    NSDictionary* errorDis = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:content];
    [script executeAndReturnError:&errorDis];

     NSLog(@" errorDis %@", errorDis);
```

The code compiles and runs as:

```
set script_text to MakeScript()
 my RunMaker(script_text)
 on RunMaker(script_text)
 set file_spec to ("/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/theScript.scpt") 
 store script script_text in file_spec replacing yes 
 end RunMaker 
 on MakeScript() 
 script 
  say "hello" 
 end script 
end MakeScript
```

Saving a script file named **theScript.scpt** in **Downloads**.
( From an existing applescript I had. it can be shortened )

Comment: still its not detecting by outlook, it there any way to read and edit the applescript file? I mean compiled one

Comment: What Happens when you open it in Applescript Editor

Comment: its opening and i can execute it but outlook is not detecting it and if i try to save the file it's says unable to save

Comment: What happens if you change the extension to .applescript ( in the code)

Comment: file is creating but Outlook is not detecting, even I am able to run this edited script programatically but outlook not want to detect this edited file :(

Comment: DO you have any idea about NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-43"?

Comment: ASFAIK -43 is does not exist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43475/discussion-between-aashish-joshi-and-markhunte)